# How do I check if an object given to me is an int [] in Java?

Tags: java

How do I check if an object given to me is an `int[]` in Java?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The way you'd expect:

```
if (theObject instanceof int[]) {
    // use it!
}
```

Arrays are `Objects`, even if they're arrays of primitives.

Comment: Yep. That's the way to do it. I knew there was a better way than my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (o instanceof int[])
{
...
}
```

Arrays are Objects in java.

Answer (score 0):

Get the runtime class of the variable if its a single dimension array the class name is like [int   if it is a 2 dimensional array the class name is [[int and if it's a 3 dimensional class name is [[[int

```
if ( j.class.Name.equals("[int")) {
   ......
}
```

Comment: Reflection would also work, but the question didn't mention multidimensional arrays.

Comment: That should be j.getClass().getName(), not j.class.Name.

Comment: j.class would work in Java 6 as well and if it's not then the point is however communicated well. However the instanceof would be better because I think it's deduced at compile time with out a call to a class method. However for the sake of providing a different proposition I'm adding this.

Comment: I downloaded Java 6 specifically to test this, and it doesn't seem to work.  "class" does not seem to be a member accessible from an instance, at least not in JDK1.6.0_13

Answer (score 0):

intanceof is simplest but to do literally what you ask.

```
if (o.getClass() == int[].class)
```

Comment: important to note: instanceof will not throw a NullPointerException if o is null, but this will